# Is it possible to run iOS 11 Simulators on Xcode 8?

Tags: iphone, macos, ios-simulator, xcode8, ios11

After all the problems that come with Xcode 9 I want to avoid having to upgrade to it until the community knows its stable.  However, I need to get iOS 11 Simulators running on Xcode 8 and can't figure a way of doing it.

I have found how to support iOS 11 Devices within Xcode 8, but I also need to run iOS 11 Simulators too.

Is this possible?  If so, please instruct me on how to do this.

Comment: I won't recommend it.For example, Xcode 8 has old frameworks. Xcode 9 has new frameworks. What if some code of frameworks get deprecated in Xcode 9? If you want Xcode 8, then instead of updating Xcode 8, download Xcode 9 from website use it side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported, but you can accomplish this by *copying* the iOS 11 simruntime bundle to ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes and then adding platform_launch_helper from iOS 10 into iOS 11 (it was removed, but Xcode 8 needs it).

Assuming your Xcode 9 is at /Applications/Xcode-9.app and Xcode 8 is at /Applications/Xcode-8.app, you can accomplish this with:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
cp -a /Applications/Xcode-9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS11.0.simruntime
ln -s /Applications/Xcode-8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/libexec/platform_launch_helper ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/platform_launch_helper
```

Note: A symlink for the main bundle won't work.  You need to copy it.  If you use a symlink, the CoreSimulatorBridge job will not load and you won't be able to install apps.

If you update Xcode 9 in the future, you should redo this to ensure you have the latest updates in your local copy.